# How do I extract validation errors in Typescript using Axios

Tags: typescript, laravel, axios, vuejs3

I am using Axios to send a request to an API that responds back with a 422 status code when there are validation errors. The API is built using The Laravel Framework. The Axios response has the following structure.

[image: Axios response]

I have the following code to get the error bag returned when there is a validation error

```
if (error.response) { // type guard since response could be undefined
  if (status === 422) {
    const data = error.response.data

    if ('errors' in data) { /** TYPESCRIPT WARNING */
      Object.keys(data.errors).forEach((key) => {

      })
    }
  }
}
```

Typescript throws a warning on the line `if ('errors' in data)` that 'data' is of type 'unknown'. I have been scratching my head for 5 hours and I simply cannot understand why I am getting this error and moreso, how to resolve it before throwing 'any' and 'object' all over the place.

Comment: Since the type of `error` is `unknown`, the type of `data`, that is `error.response.data` is unknown as well. So when you do a `if( "errors" in data )` you're checking for `errors` to exist on an `unknown` type. What you should b doing instead is `if ( typeof data === "object" && "errors" in data )`, and that should take care of it.

Comment: @0xts I have actually specified the error type as AxiosError so I am not sure I understand exactly why the error would be unknown. However, your solution does work with a tiny, little adjustment. I added the data check since typescript complained that the value might be null.

`if (data && typeof data === 'object' && 'errors' in data)`

Comment: Then it's probable that the definition of `AxiosError` has `data` defined as `unknown`. You can skip checking for type of data and simply do `if( data && "errors" in data )` and that'll work as well.

Comment: @0xts Yes, data is indeed unknown. If I skip checking the type, I get a new error, `Type '{}' may represent a primitive value, which is not permitted as the right operand of the 'in'`. Typescript really is fun XD